How to delete a row on TanStack Table
I created a Datatable component following the guide on Shadcn, their table uses TanStack React-table. The component works fine but i'm having trouble connecting it to my backend to perform CRUD oprations. The API for the communication between front and back is built with tRPC. I can call the procedures just fine and the data changes in the database but when i try to delete an item (literally pick the id from the row and use it to call the procedure to eliminate from the database) the item is deleted successfully but the table does not update itself unless I manually reload the page.
This is the page that shows the Datatable component:
const AddProductButton = () => {
  return (
    <div className="ml-2">
      {" "}
      <Link
        className={buttonVariants({
          size: "default",
          variant: "default",
        })}
        href={"/dashboard/products/new-product"}
      >
        New Product
      </Link>{" "}
    </div>
  );
};

const ProductsPage = () => {
  const { data } = trpc.getAllProductsNofilter.useQuery();
  
  const columns: ColumnDef<ProductType>[] = [
    {
      id: "select",
      header: ({ table }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={
            table.getIsAllPageRowsSelected() ||
            (table.getIsSomePageRowsSelected() && "indeterminate")
          }
          onCheckedChange={(value) => table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label="Select all"
        />
      ),
      cell: ({ row }) => (
        <Checkbox
          checked={row.getIsSelected()}
          onCheckedChange={(value) => row.toggleSelected(!!value)}
          aria-label="Select row"
        />
      ),
      enableSorting: false,
      enableHiding: false,
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "imgurl",
      header: "Picture",
      cell: ({ row }) => {
        const iURL = row.getValue("imgurl") as string;
        return (
          <div>
            <Image src={iURL} alt="image" height={"80"} width={"80"} />
          </div>
        );
      },
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "name",
      header: "Name",
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "category",
      header: "Category",
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "brand",
      header: "Brand",
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "size",
      header: "Size",
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "stock",
      header: "Stock",
    },
    {
      accessorKey: "price",
      header: "Price",
      cell: ({ row }) => {
        const amount = parseFloat(row.getValue("price"));

        // Format the amount as a dollar amount
        const formatted = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
          style: "currency",
          currency: "USD",
        }).format(amount);

        return <div>{formatted}</div>;
      },
    },
    {
      id: "actions",
      enableHiding: false,
      cell: ({ row }) => {
        const product = row.original;

        return (
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
              <Button variant="ghost" className="h-8 w-8 p-0">
                <span className="sr-only">Open menu</span>
                <MoreHorizontal className="h-4 w-4" />
              </Button>
            </DropdownMenuTrigger>
            <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
              <DropdownMenuLabel>Actions</DropdownMenuLabel>
              <DropdownMenuItem
                onClick={() => navigator.clipboard.writeText(product.id)}
              >
                Copy product ID
              </DropdownMenuItem>
              <DropdownMenuSeparator />
              <DropdownMenuItem>Modify Product</DropdownMenuItem>
              <DropdownMenuItem>Delete Product</DropdownMenuItem>
            </DropdownMenuContent>
          </DropdownMenu>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto pt-6 ">
      {data && (
        <DataTable
          addButton={<AddProductButton />}
          classname="max-h-[68vh] overflow-auto"
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductsPage;

And this is the Datatable component:
export function DataTable<TData, TValue>({
  columns,
  data,
  classname,
  addButton,
  deleteAllSelected = true,
}: DataTableProps<TData, TValue>) {

  const [filtertype, setFilterType] = useState("name");
  const [columnFilters, setColumnFilters] = useState<ColumnFiltersState>([]);
  const [rowSelection, setRowSelection] = useState({});
  const [columnVisibility, setColumnVisibility] = useState<VisibilityState>({});
  const [reRender, setReRender] = useState(false)
  const mutation = trpc.deleteManyProducts.useMutation()
  const table = useReactTable({
    data,
    columns,
    getCoreRowModel: getCoreRowModel(),
    getPaginationRowModel: getPaginationRowModel(),
    onColumnFiltersChange: setColumnFilters,
    getFilteredRowModel: getFilteredRowModel(),
    onRowSelectionChange: setRowSelection,
    onColumnVisibilityChange: setColumnVisibility,
    state: {
      columnFilters,
      rowSelection,
      columnVisibility,
    },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="flex items-center py-4">
        <Input
          placeholder={`Filter by ${filtertype}...`}
          value={
            (table.getColumn(filtertype)?.getFilterValue() as string) ?? ""
          }
          onChange={(event) =>
            table.getColumn(filtertype)?.setFilterValue(event.target.value)
          }
          className="max-w-sm mr-2"
        />
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <div>
              <Button variant="outline" className=" px-3">
                Change Filter
              </Button>
            </div>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setFilterType("name")}>
              Name
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setFilterType("brand")}>
              Brand
            </DropdownMenuItem>
            <DropdownMenuItem onClick={() => setFilterType("category")}>
              Category
            </DropdownMenuItem>
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>

        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
            <Button variant="outline" className="ml-auto">
              Columns
            </Button>
          </DropdownMenuTrigger>
          <DropdownMenuContent align="end">
            {table
              .getAllColumns()
              .filter((column) => column.getCanHide())
              .map((column) => {
                return (
                  <DropdownMenuCheckboxItem
                    key={column.id}
                    className="capitalize"
                    checked={column.getIsVisible()}
                    onCheckedChange={(value) =>
                      column.toggleVisibility(!!value)
                    }
                  >
                    {column.id}
                  </DropdownMenuCheckboxItem>
                );
              })}
          </DropdownMenuContent>
        </DropdownMenu>
        {deleteAllSelected && (
          <Button
            className="ml-2"
            disabled={table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length === 0}
            onClick={() => {
              const rowModel = table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel();
              const idList = rowModel.rows.map((row) => row.original.id)
              mutation.mutate({idList: idList as string[]})
              table.toggleAllPageRowsSelected(false)
            }}
          >
            Delete selected rows
          </Button>
        )}

        {addButton}
      </div>
      {/* <FilteringComponent /> */}
      <div className={cn("rounded-md border", classname)}>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader>
            {table.getHeaderGroups().map((headerGroup) => (
              <TableRow key={headerGroup.id}>
                {headerGroup.headers.map((header) => {
                  return (
                    <TableHead key={header.id}>
                      {header.isPlaceholder
                        ? null
                        : flexRender(
                            header.column.columnDef.header,
                            header.getContext()
                          )}
                    </TableHead>
                  );
                })}
              </TableRow>
            ))}
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {table.getRowModel().rows?.length ? (
              table.getRowModel().rows.map((row) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data-state={row.getIsSelected() && "selected"}
                >
                  {row.getVisibleCells().map((cell) => (
                    <TableCell key={cell.id}>
                      {flexRender(
                        cell.column.columnDef.cell,
                        cell.getContext()
                      )}
                    </TableCell>
                  ))}
                </TableRow>
              ))
            ) : (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell
                  colSpan={columns.length}
                  className="h-24 text-center"
                >
                  No results.
                </TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-end space-x-2 py-4">
        <div className="flex-1 text-sm text-muted-foreground">
          {table.getFilteredSelectedRowModel().rows.length} of{" "}
          {table.getFilteredRowModel().rows.length} row(s) selected.
        </div>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => table.previousPage()}
          disabled={!table.getCanPreviousPage()}
        >
          Previous
        </Button>
        <Button
          variant="outline"
          size="sm"
          onClick={() => table.nextPage()}
          disabled={!table.getCanNextPage()}
        >
          Next
        </Button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

Any idea why this might happen?
I've tried to manually refetch the data after deleting, and also tried to trigger a re-render on both the table and the parent component at the end of the delete function.

Your mutation function should invalidate your query cache to get the latest version from the backend.
